# How to turn on code folding for functions in Visual Studio 2008?

Tags: visual-studio-2008

I'm using Visual Studio 2008 to write C and C++ code.  Right now it does not fold ANY code, and it's really annoying.  It does not fold functions, for loops, or anything at all.  I'd really like, at the very least, to be able to fold functions.

Can anyone tell me exactly where this option might be located?  I feel like I've looked everywhere in the options.

Answer (score 2):

To control code folding and other formatting options for aspx and html pages, go to: Tools > Options > Text Editor > HTML > Formatting > Tag Specific Options. From there, you can set default behaviors for general server or client tags, depending on whether they support content or not.

Comment: This does not answer the question, but I still found it useful.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio, go to the Options (**Tools > Options**).

Then navigate to **Text Editor > C/C++ > Formatting** and check the option "**Enter outlining mode when files open**"

That should fix the problem.